# transform excel format

Tags: excel

Environment: Microsoft Excel 2003, 07, or 10

Is there an easy way to transform

```
lines 1-11
```

into

```
lines 15-20
```

[image]

Comment: Short answer, no. Long answer, there's no real organization in the first place. When categories, subcategories, and IDs are in the same column, unless there is some naming convention to discern between them (e.g. "Sub" prefaces each subcategory) then you'll have to do it manually. There doesn't seem to be any pattern to identifying what would be an ID, category1, or category2 (cat1 and cat2 are both in bold, so you can't base it off formatting), so there's no easy way to programatically reorganize your data. Going forward, I'd say to request your source data is organized in the first place.

Comment: what if there was some sort of pattern to identify category, sub, and id, would it be easy then? If so, how?

Comment: If there is a pattern, then I'd suggest using VBA. If you're not very familiar with VBA and don't have time to learn, then you're better off doing this manually (unless you're working with thousands of IDs) rather than hunting for a solution online. Otherwise, I suggest trying to code something and posting your attempts here where people can help you revise. SO, in general, is not here to provide code welfare, so at least make an honest effort before asking for a complete solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be easily done with few additional basic test formulas.

Add the columns in your table as per the screenshot below and filter your table with is_id column TRUE data.

Enjoy, you're welcome.

[image]